# Match two images almost pixel-perfectly, but be able to match only slightly darker brightness values with OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to compare two images with cv2, `tile` and `tlcropped`. It works, but as long as the two images are pixel-perfect and color value-perfect.

I want it to be pixel-perfect, but thing is... I don't want it to have to be the exact same color value, but the closest one. I am trying to compare tiles in these two images:

**The screenshot**

[image: The screenshot]

**The tile itself**

[image: The tile itself]

But, the screenshots have very slightly darker RGB values compared to the stand-alone tile picture. How would I get it to stay pixel-perfect but match at least slightly different brightness values, but not enough to get the wrong tile? Been thinking about this for a while now and haven't been able to come up with a good solution yet.

(I'm using cv2, not cv.)
Here's my comparison code right now, by the way, if you want it:

```
for tileN in range(1, tilecount):
    tilePosY = tileN*h;

    tlcropped = tlset[ tilePosY: tilePosY+16,   0: w]

    if ((tile==tlcropped).all()):
        match_found = True
        break;
```

Comment: you could try to convert each pixel (image and template) to its LBP representation and search for perfect matches, but this might be too wide tolerance. Maybe you can fuse it with ssd threshold or local normalization.

Comment: Another way to state this problem, which might lead to some ideas for you to try, is that you want the "edges" to match up but allow for some error in the pixel values.